# Editing the data in A JSON file from JS working wrong (discord.js coding)

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

OK so this might be a little confusing but I'll try to explain this as clear as possible.

I'm working on a way to get points and gamble the points on my discord bot. Heres the code on how the points work. (basically every message you send in a server that the bot is in = 1 point)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client()
const fs = require('fs')
let UserData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./storage/Userdata.json', 'utf8'))

Client.on('message', async msg => {
    
    if(!UserData[msg.author.id]) Userdata[msg.author.id] = {
        Points: 0
    }
    
    UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints++
    
    let prefix = 'dr/'
    let msgsections = msg.content.split(" ")
    let cmd = msgsections[0].toLowerCase();
    let args = msgsections.slice(1);
    let bruh = cmd.split(prefix)
    let points = UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints
    let commandfile = Client.commands.get(bruh[1])
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(Client, msg, args, points, UserData)

})
```

So now im tying to make a command where u can gamble the points so basically when you gamble it randomly selects between taking all your points that you gambled and deleting them or giving you double the points.

heres the code (in a different file)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const botinfo = require('../BotInfo.json');
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args, points, UserData) => {

    let amount = args[0]
    let won = amount*2
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)

    if (amount > points) return msg.channel.send('You don't have enough points to gamble this amount!')
    if (!amount) return msg.channel.send('Please enter an amount you want to gamble')
    if (random === 0) {
        UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints -= amount
        msg.channel.send(`You just gambled ${amount} points and lost all of them lol. You now have ${UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints} points`)
        
    } else if (random === 1) {
        UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints += amount
        msg.channel.send(`You just gambled \*${amount} points\* and won back ${won} points! you now have ${UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints} points`)
        
    }
}  

module.exports.config = {
    name: 'gamble',
    aliases: []
}
```

Every time I run the command when I loose it takes away the current amount of points but when I win it adds an insane amount of points and I don't know why.  ^

[screenshot](https://drizzy.is-terrible.com/JFoUep)

Comment: can you add a description of "an insane amount of points"? the image host is blocked for me

Comment: additionally i spot two typos that should be causing errors: `UserData[msg.autor.id].Points++` author is spelled wrong and `const client = new Discord.Client()` is lowercase client when you use uppercase Client in code

Comment: these are already fixed my copy and paste isnt working so i had to manually write out the code here fixing the typos right away also its giving me like 10423 points

Comment: ...your copy-paste isn't working? Seems like you got other problems to solve that are of much higher priority than this.

Comment: thats not gonna solve itself here is it

Comment: @IsraelProductionzz add some `console.log()`s around the function to see where the values are wrong. also i notice you increment UserData.Points but never UserData.DrizziPoints, perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: thats another typo my bad points++ is supossed to be  drizzipoints++

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! Thanks for any help

The issue was I was adding a string to an int Here

```js
    } else if (random === 1) {
        UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints += amount
        msg.channel.send(`You just gambled \*${amount} points\* and won back ${won} points! you now have ${UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints} points`)
```

the fix was just to use parseInt()

```js
} else if (random === 1) {
        UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints += parseInt(amount,10)
        msg.channel.send(`You just gambled \*${amount} points\* and won back ${won} points! you now have ${UserData[msg.author.id].DrizziPoints} points`)
```